# continuous image of a locally compact space is locally compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness, open-map

> Is continuous image of a locally compact space is locally compact?
>
> Let $X$ be locally compact(l.c.). Let $f: X\to Y$ be continuous and surjective.

A space $X$ is locally compact if for each $x\in X$ such that $\exists $ a  compact set $V$ such that $x\in U\subset V$ for some open set $U$ containing $x$.

To show that $Y$ is locally compact

**My try:**
Let $y=f(x)\in Y$ and let $V\subset Y$ be an open set containing $y$.then $x\in f^{-1}(V)\subset X$ .As $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ which is locally compact so there exists a compact set $C\subset X$ such that $x\in f^{-1}(V)\subset C\subset X\implies f(x)\subset V\subset f(C)\subset Y$ Now $f(C)$ being continuous image of  a compact set is compact.

Thus proved. But the problem is it has been given that only continuity will not do the map has to be open also.

Please find mistakes in the proof if it exists.

Comment: Take $V = Y$ in your proof. What is the problem?

Comment: Your definition of locally compact seems to imply that the space is compact, take $U = X$.

Comment: For a counterexample : Let $X = (\mathbb{Q}, \tau_{\text{discrete}})$ and $Y = (\mathbb{Q},\tau_{\text{usual}})$. Consider $f: X \to Y$ to be the identity map. $X$ is locally compact where as $Y = f(X)$ is not

Comment: thanks for the example ;@S.C.

Comment: @learnmore No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: @S.C.: Indeed, you could let $X$ be any non-locally compact space whatsoever, $X_\text{disc}$ the discrete space with the same underlying set, and consider the identity map $X_\text{disc} \to X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer ;

Let  $y=f(x)\in Y $ then since $X$ is locally compact $x\in X$ has a compact neighborhood i.e there exists an open set $U $ contained in a compact set $V$ i.e. $x\in U\subset V$ then $f(x)\in f(U)\subset f(V)$

Now $f$ being open $f(U)$ is open in $Y$ and continuous image of a  compact set being compact implies $f(V)$ is compact

Comment: Why can we say that f is open? Does this follow from continuous en surjective?

Answer (score 3):

The open set $f^{-1}(V)$ need not be contained in a compact set, so what you have to do is that using locally compactness of $X$ there is a open set $x \in U$ such that there is a compact set $C$ and $U \subset C$. Now take the intersection $U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ and take the image $f( U \cap f^{-1}(V)) \subset f(C)$ now $f$ being open the image is open and $f$ being continuous $f(C)$ is compact. Thus we get locally compactness. The openness condition is required.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the flaw in the proposer's initial attempt. As  in the comments, if $X$ is not compact and $V=Y$ there is no compact  $C\subset X$ with $f^{-1}V\subset C$.