# Images of locally compact spaces through Borel maps

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $Y$ a Hausdorff space and

$f : X \to Y$

a Borel map. Is $f(Y)$ locally compact?

Comment: ok. it seems that the answer is "no": even continuity seems to be not enough, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287344/continuous-image-of-a-locally-compact-space-is-locally-compact?rq=1

Comment: no, every space is the continuous image of a discrete space , which are locally compact.