# Proper in one argument implies total properness?

Tags: general-topology, proper-maps

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Furthermore, $X$ is compact. We have a continuous map
$$f : X \times Y \to Z$$
satisfying that for every fixed $x \in X$ the map
$$f_x\colon Y \to Z , \quad y \mapsto f(x,y)$$
is proper. Does this imply that $f$ itself is proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It need not be that $f$ is proper.

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x,t)=tx^2+x.$$
This a homotopy of proper maps $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. However $f$ is not a proper map. To see this observe that the sequence $(-n,1/n)$ is unbounded in the domain but satisfies $f(-n,1/n)=0$. Thus $f^{-1}(0)$ is not compact.

I learned of this counterexample from the introduction of Thomas Rot's paper *Homotopy classes of proper maps out of vector bundles* ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08073)).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a pretty hard nut. I came so close to a solution with some theorems I've never heard before, but something is still missing. The proof works for finite $X$ though. Here is what I have so far:

Continuous maps into locally compact spaces are proper iff closed (See [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+compact+topological+space), Proposition 4.1.). It is therefore sufficient to prove, that $f$ is closed. Let $x\in X$. Since $X$ is a Hausdorff space, the singleton subset $\{x\}\subseteq X$ is closed. Because of the definition of the product topology, $\{x\}\times Y=\pi_X^{-1}(\{x\})$ is closed, where $\pi_X\colon X\times Y\rightarrow X,(x,y)\mapsto x$ is the canonical projection.

Let $A\subseteq X\times Y$ be closed, then $A\cap(\{x\}\times Y)$ is closed. Let $A_x=\pi_Y(A\cap(\{x\}\times Y))\subseteq Y$ be the slice of $A$ through $\{x\}$. Since $X$ is compact, the projection map $\pi_Y\colon X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ is closed (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/projection-map-being-a-closed-map), but with $X$ and $Y$ switched.) and therefore $A_x$ is closed (and locally compact since the superset $Y$ is). We have:
\begin{equation}
A=\bigcup_{x\in X}A\cap(\{x\}\times Y)
=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}\times A_x.
\end{equation}
Since $f_x$ is proper, it is closed. Therefore $f_x(A_x)$ is closed (and locally compact since the superset $Y$ is) and we have:
\begin{equation}
f(A)=\bigcup_{x\in X}f(\{x\}\times A_x)
=\bigcup_{x\in X}f_x(A_x).
\end{equation}
If $X$ is finite, $f(A)$ would be closed as the finite union of closed sets and we would already be finished, so assume it's not. $f_x(A_x)^\complement$ is open and also dense in $Y$, since:
\begin{equation}
\overline{f_x(A_x)^\complement}
=(f_x(A_x)^\circ)^\complement
=(f(\{x\}\times A_x)^\circ)^\complement
\supseteq f((\{x\}\times A_x)^\circ)^\complement
=f(\{x\}^\circ\times A_x^\circ)^\complement
=\emptyset^\complement
=Y.
\end{equation}
Since $Y$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, the open and dense subset $f_x(A_x)^\complement$ is locally compact (See [here](https://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/mfrankland/Math535/Math535_1010.pdf), Corollary 1.10.). Since $f$ is continuous, $f_x(A_x)$ is locally compact (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287344/continuous-image-of-a-locally-compact-space-is-locally-compact)).

(Arbitrary) intersections of locally compact subsets in Hausdorff spaces are locally compact (using the definition that every open neighborhood is the superset of a compact neighborhood), since the compact neighborhoods are all closed (due to the superset being Hausdorff), their (arbitrary) intersection being closed and therefore compact (since being included in all compact neighborhoods).

Therefore $f(A)=\bigcap_{x\in X}f_x(A_x)^\complement$ is locally compact and can be written as $f(A)=B\cap C$ with $B,C\subseteq Z$, where $B$ is closed and $C$ is open (See [here](https://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/mfrankland/Math535/Math535_1010.pdf), Proposition 1.9.). Well, the $C$ ruins it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one first comment to your first paragraph: For finite $X$ the question is trivial, I guess, because finite unions of compact sets are compact.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's trivial in that case. I will still think about how to complete my answer.

Comment: I thought about the problem a little bit longer and I guess I came up with a proof in case closedness can be described using converging sequences. Surely, the argument works with nets as well. I'll write it in a post in maybe 90 minutes. I have a meeting before.

Comment: Looking forward to it. I have not made any progress the last hour and will stop now.

Comment: I just posted my proof. What do you think about it? Does it make sense?

Comment: Oh shit. I just realized that your Proposition 4.1 doesn't state "if and only if". It states only one direction and we need the other direction.

Comment: Oh shit. You're right, I overlooked that. I haven't heard of the theorem before. In this case, my answer only provides some useful theorems. I will look at your proof.

Comment: My proof does not work then. It was based on your iff statement.

Comment: I just tried finding a counterexample, but failed. Nonetheless, maybe it gives you an idea:

Assume $X$ is compact and $Y$ is not, then $\pi_X\colon X\times Y\rightarrow X$ is not proper since $X$ is compact, but $\pi_X^{-1}(X)=X\times Y$ is not. (If $X\times Y$ was compact, then $Y=\pi_Y(X\times Y)$ would be as well because $\pi_Y$ is continuous due to the definition of the prodcut topology.) The functions $(\pi_X)_x\colon Y\rightarrow X,y\mapsto\pi_X(x,y)=x$ are the constant maps, but since $Y$ is not compact, they unfortnutly aren't proper.

Answer (score 0):

I present here a proof I came up with which works in case closedness can be described using converging sequences. I guess it won't be a problem to generalize this to the general case using nets instead of sequences.

By what Samuel Adrian Antz pointed out we have to show that $f$ maps closed subsets to closed subsets. Let $C \subset X \times Y$ be closed and let $((x_n,y_n))_n \in C$ be a sequence such that $(f(x_n,y_n))_n$ converges to a point $z \in Z$. We have to show $z \in f(C)$.

Since $X$ is compact, we find a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ which converges in $X$, lets say to a point $x$. Without loss of generality $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$.

Because $f$ is continuous the sequence  $(f(x,y_n))_n$ converges to $z$. Let $U$ be a compact neighborhood of $z$. Then $f_x^{-1}(U)$ is compact and contains almost all $y_n$. In particular the limit $y \in Y$ of a subsequence of $(y_n)_n$ is contained in $f_x^{-1}(U)$. Without loss of generality $(y_n)_n$ converges to $y$.

Hence, we have shown that $((x_n,y_n))_n$ converges to $(x,y)$. Because $C$ is closed we have $(x,y)\in C$ which proves $z \in f(C)$.

I hope this proof is correct. Any comments?

Comment: The case holds, being compact and sequence compact is not equivalent in general, but in Hausdorff spaces. (I guess you noticed, you also used the Hausdorff condition of $X$ and $Y$ to guarantee the limit points are unique.) I would also use a different variable for the subsequences, but that's taste. I think the proof works.

Comment: Compactness and sequential compactness are not equivalent for Hausdorff spaces @SamuelAdrianAntz